# Proper way to install SVNKit 1.7.x in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, subversive

Folks,

I am a bit confused on how to get SVNKit 1.7 Beta 3 to work under Eclipse Indigo.

Using the Eclipse update site mentioned at http://svnkit.com/download.php, I installed new software from http://eclipse.svnkit.com/1.7.x. I selected both the items on the list, the core SVNKit Library and optional JNA Library.

The installation seems to have succeeded. When I look at the list of installed software, I see SVN Library 1.70 Beta 3 in the list.

However, Eclipse still does not recognized that my projects are source controlled.

When I go to Preferences, all I see is SVNKit 1.3.6-v1. I do not see SVNKit 1.7.

Is there some other step that I am missing? How do I get Subversive to recognized my Subversion 1.7 based projects?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Regards,
Peter

Comment: After a lot of frustration, I just removed Subversive and installed Subclipse instead. This is the first time I am using Subclipse. So far, it seems to work alright and is able to deal with subversion 1.7 format just fine.

Comment: Personally I like Subversive much more than Subclipse...so I hope, wait and pray for SVNKit1.7 support in Subversive...

Comment: every listed link for an updatesite here responds with a 404? Where do I get the current version of SVNKit and how do I install it? Fuzzing around for an hour now and got nothing :(

Answer (score 15):

To install SVNKit as an Eclipse plugin or to make sure that you have the latest version installed, use http://eclipse.svnkit.com/1.7.x/ as an update site location in Eclipse Update Manager.

- List item In Eclipse menu select Help->Software Updates
- List item Then choose 'Available Software' tab
- List item Click 'Add Site...' button
- List item Type http://eclipse.svnkit.com/1.7.x/ in the 'Location' field and press 'OK'.
- List item Check the new site (it should appear in the list of update sites) and follow further steps as prompted by Eclipse.

---

Use http://eclipse.svnkit.com/1.3.x/ as an update site location to get older version of SVNKit (1.3.8).

Answer (score 4):

In order to install SVNKit 1.7.x for Subversive I've opened Eclipse > Help > Install new software and used the link from http://www.polarion.com/products/svn/subversive/download.php page:

> http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/3.0/kepler-site/ – [required] Subversive SVN Connectors

After that new connector appeared under Eclipse Preferences.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the records, as of March 2013, Subversive does seem to work with SVNKit 1.7.

I installed both (SVNKit [1.7.8](http://eclipse.svnkit.com/1.7.x) and then Subversive [Service Release 1.0.1](http://download.eclipse.org/technology/subversive/1.0/update-site-1.0.1/)) on Eclipse **Indigo** and haven't run into any problems so far.

If you want to give it a try, just make sure to uninstall the previous version first, as the Subversive latest releases page points out:

> **Subversive 0.7 to 1.0 Upgrade Notes**
>
> If need to update Subversive from 0.7.x to the 1.0.0 version,
> uninstall the previously installed Subversive 0.7.x plug-in version
> first. Otherwise during the installation process you'll be blocked by
> the old connectors version that is incompatible with the 1.0.0 release
> and couldn't be installed simultaneously with the main plug-in due to
> the installation UI restrictions.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works with Subclipse, but not Subversive.