# Subversion upgrade to from 1.6 to 1.7

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

Im trying to upgrade Subversion from 1.6 to 1.7 and having issues.

Im using Linux Redhat 5, Im installing SVN server only and not using Apache. I'm then accessing subversion via Eclipse Kepler. I have used the rpm from CollbaNet to upgrade my version of SVN and all appears to have worked

When I run svn --version, I get

svn, version 1.7.16 (r1569520)
   compiled Apr  9 2014, 14:32:02

I have then checked out a few test branches from my repository but Im not seeing any change or benefit. The working copy still has an .svn folder in every directory and still takes ages to check out or commit changes .

Is there anything Im missing from the install, I followed the instructions from CollabNet to the letter. Do I need to do anything to eclipse to make it recognise 1.7?

I should add this is on a test server running parallel to our live version of svn. Eclipse has repositories from both servers.

Apologies if you need more information, if you do let me know and I will provide as needed

thanks

Comment: In your local SVN in Eclipse, you need to say Team -- Upgrade (right click on Project), then you'll switch to the new SVN style. That should do it.

Comment: thanks, however I cant see an 'upgrade' option under the team sub menu

Comment: Not near the bottom: Refresh/Cleanup, Upgrade, Disconnect, Upgrade projects... Update your SVN client in Eclipse?

Comment: @jedison he has to upgrade the plug-in first.

Comment: @bahrep, yeah that is what I commented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, the server-side upgrade does not affect your client. The client is still based on Subversion 1.6. You have to upgrade the client to benefit from [the client-side improvements](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html#wc-ng).

In other words, upgrade the svn plug-in that you use in Eclipse ([Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) / [Subversive](https://www.eclipse.org/subversive/) or whatever you use in the IDE) to the latest version.

Comment: for anyone else on this journey, i used http://matsim.org/docs/devguide/installing-subclipse. However Im using subclipse and not subversive so requirements may differ.

If yore using subversive check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607556/proper-way-to-install-svnkit-1-7-x-in-eclipse

Comment: Note, you can actually get many of the client benefits by updating the client even if you DON'T update the server.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I noticed this after spending about a day testing it all out! So if I only update eclipse, then I get the benefits I need?

Answer (score 0):

```
 sudo yum update
 sudo yum groupinstall "Development tools"
 sudo yum groupinstall "Additional Development"
 wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/subversion/subversion-1.7.8.tar.gz
 tar zxvf subversion-1.7.8.tar.gz
 cd subversion-1.7.8
 ./get-deps.sh
 ./configure
 make
 make check
 sudo make install
```

On my system this seems to put the binary in /usr/local/bin/svn whereas the 1.6 binary is in /usr/bin/svn so you might need set up an alias.